# How do I group by getting 2 specific values within a single column in Python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

How do I extract the two different values (dog and cat) and then combine them under a new Dataframe

I tried

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'Animal':['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'dog', 'bird', 'bird'],'Age':[1,3,5,3,4,2]})
df[(df['Animal'] == 'cat')&(df['Animal']=='dog')]
```

But when trying to locate 2 different values it only shows the top row "Animal Age"

I can find all of the dog values

```
df[(df['Animal'] == 'dog')]
```

but I'm not able to extract dog and cat rows at the same time from the Animal column

Comment: `df[df['Animal'].isin(['cat', 'dog'])]`

Answer (score 0):

The condition you are using to filter your results is `&` which in your case, both cat and dog do not happen on the same row. You need to use `|` (i.e., union).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal':['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'dog', 'bird', 'bird'],'Age':[1,3,5,3,4,2]})
df[(df['Animal'] == 'cat')|(df['Animal']=='dog')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `or` conditional, if you use `and`, both cat and dog has to be true. Which makes an empty dataframe:

```
df[(df['Animal'] == 'cat') | (df['Animal']=='dog')]
```